# Attempting to update iDRAC firmware with racadm, getting error "RAC923 : The file path is too long"

Tags: dell-poweredge, rhel7, dell-openmanage

Per title, I'm attempting to update iDRAC on an R720 server running RHEL7.

I obtained the correct firwmare file by going to Dell's support site, entering my service tag, then filtering down to the iDRAC and Lifecycle controller firmware update. I downloaded the .EXE file.

When I issue the racadm update command, it responds with an error stating the filename is too long. I have not edited the filename, it is as downloaded from Dell.

```
[acoder@box idracfw]# racadm update -f iDRAC-with-Lifecycle-Controller_Firmware_0GHF4_WN64_2.65.65.65_A00.EXE 
Copying..
Transfering...
Applying Update.... Depending on the file size this operation might take several minutes, do not interrupt the process.
ERROR: RAC923 : The file path is too long.
       Try the same command with a shorter file path
       (specified with the -f parameter) which is less than
       64 characters in length.
```

I also tried renaming the firmware file to a shorter name, but this failed I presume due to a checksum issue.

```
[acoder@box idracfw]# mv iDRAC-with-Lifecycle-Controller_Firmware_0GHF4_WN64_2.65.65.65_A00.EXE iDRAC-w-LC-Contr_Fw_0GHF4_WN64_2.65.65.65_A00.EXE 
[acoder@box idracfw]# racadm update -f iDRAC-w-LC-Contr_Fw_0GHF4_WN64_2.65.65.65_A00.EXE 
Copying..
Transfering...
Applying Update.... Depending on the file size this operation might take several minutes, do not interrupt the process.
ERROR: RAC989: Unable to apply the iDRAC-w-LC-Contr_Fw_0GHF4_WN64_2.65.65.65_A00.EXE firmware update.
       The file used for the operation is invalid. For the list of 
       supported files, use "racadm help update". For the correct version of 
       the file specific to the system, contact the service provider.
```

The same errors happen regardless of architecture (there are 64 and 32 bit versions of the firmware file)

What is the best way around this error?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an iDRAC enterprise please use the web UI to update with the .exe, it will bypass that error.

Comment: I am unable to get web UI to pull up, hence using racadm

Comment: @acoder Problem to pull up, you mean the IP is not responding ? or the browser refuse to open, old insecure certificate etc..) as you can use a old portable firefox to by pass that problem.

Comment: the IP is responsive but iDRAC is not pulling up. I presume because I tried to update and it failed with filename too long, that was the only change made.

Comment: @acoder You can restart / reset the iDRAC then,  racadm racreset soft  or racadm restart. let me know if it answer after.

Comment: I tried `racadm racreset soft`, but still cannot access the web client. `racadm restart` yields "ERROR: Invalid subcommand specified."