# Updating iDRAC firmware via Lifecycle Controller and USB

Tags: dell-poweredge, drac, firmware, lifecycle, firmware-update

A previously working iDRAC under a R720 server running RHEL 7 became borked when attempting a iDRAC firmware update via `racadm`. I used my Dell Service Tag to obtain the correct firmware file for this machine.

The update failed, and we are no longer able to access the interface via web (server unreachable). This started happening immediately following the failed update attempt.

When I subsequently went back and tried to install the update again via

```
racadm update -f iDRAC-w-LC-Contr_Fw_0GHF4_WN64_2.65.65.65_A00.EXE
```

`racadm` errored out with [File path is too long](https://serverfault.com/questions/1142075/attempting-to-update-idrac-firmware-with-racadm-getting-error-rac923-the-fil) (this issue did not see any answers, and the only comment did not work).

`dsu` shows no updates available.

I then attempted to update firmware via reboot into `Lifecycle Controller` and a USB thumb drive. Dell's help files are somewhat vague in what file types are needed so I ended up trying several things.

First was copying the iDRAC firmware EXE file (and nothing else) on a USB drive formatted to FAT32.  `Lifecycle Controller` initially saw the USB drive, but couldn't find a valid update file.

I then downloaded and burned the Linux Driver Pack, which came as an ISO. I burned that to the thumb drive and rebooted into `Lifecycle Controller`. This time the USB drive was not recognized at all. The filesystem type is showing `iso9660`, I burned using `USB Image Writer` under Ubuntu.

I tried again with the Windows Driver Pack, which also came as ISO. Same result, the USB drive was not recognized after booting into `Lifecycle Controller` and going to local drive, next, etc.

I tried setting a temporary Static IP in `Lifecycle Controller`, hoping I could get updates via [HTTPS method](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000128133/poweredge-server-lifecycle-controller-update). LC showed downloading Catalog, then errored out saying I had an invalid network configuration (with a known good network config).

I'm running out of options.

Again, I cannot access the web iDRAC now - I wish I'd known to do the update there, but here I am.

Can someone help fill in some blanks on what I am doing wrong to get updates via `Lifecycle Controller` with a USB thumb drive? What file(s) are needed (and will be recognized by Lifecycle Controller) on the FAT32 drive?

Comment: The last time I had to use a driver pack ISO the only way to use it was to actually burn it on a DVD. Since DVD drives are pretty rare nowadays on servers I'd try to attach one via USB, but I don't know if that is supported.